# Android Intent type video

Tags: android, android-intent

For selecting a video i use the following code.

```
Intent pickMedia = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
pickMedia.setType("video/*");
startActivityForResult(pickMedia, 12345);
```

My question i possible to set to show filtered videos ? Something like only videos with length no more than 2 min or size no more than 200 MB .

Answer (score 0):

> My question i possible to set to show filtered videos ?

Not via `ACTION_GET_CONTENT`. If the data you seek is part of the `MediaStore`, you are welcome to query the `MediaStore` for videos matching your criteria, then create your own UI to present them to the user for selection (e.g., `ListView`, `RecyclerView`).